# Linux Ubuntu error concerning libstdc++.so.6 during Gromacs make

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, makefile, libstdc++

I'm trying to install Gromacs on an Ubuntu 20.04 build. The machine is about 8 hours old, so I shouldn't be fighting too much legacy software or dependencies. However, I have been struggling with libstdc++.so.6.

When I try make after a successful cmake I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/methane-water-integration.dir/methane-water-integration.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZSt20__throw_length_errorPKc@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [api/nblib/samples/CMakeFiles/methane-water-integration.dir/build.make:87: bin/methane-water-integration] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4790: api/nblib/samples/CMakeFiles/methane-water-integration.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

Looking in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gn`u I see these files:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  2 root root        19 Apr 28  2021 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2186464 Apr 28  2021 libstdc++.so.6.0.29
```

Thanks

**UPDATE #1**
Having using `make VERBOSE=1` the extended error is:

```
[ 95%] Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/methane-water-integration
cd /home/anthony/Downloads/gromacs-2022.3/build/api/nblib/samples && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/methane-water-integration.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/gcc  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -Wl,-rpath,/home/anthony/anaconda3/lib   CMakeFiles/methane-water-integration.dir/methane-water-integration.cpp.o  -o ../../../bin/methane-water-integration  -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN/../lib" ../../../lib/libnblib_gmx.so.0.1.0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgomp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/anthony/Downloads/gromacs-2022.3/build/lib 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/methane-water-integration.dir/methane-water-integration.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZSt20__throw_length_errorPKc@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [api/nblib/samples/CMakeFiles/methane-water-integration.dir/build.make:87: bin/methane-water-integration] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anthony/Downloads/gromacs-2022.3/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4790: api/nblib/samples/CMakeFiles/methane-water-integration.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anthony/Downloads/gromacs-2022.3/build'
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

**UPDATE #2**

Concerning what my C/C++ compilers are, I see this at cmake:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python3: /home/anthony/anaconda3/bin/python3.9 (found suitable version "3.9.12", minimum required is "3.7") found components: Interpreter Development 
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")
```

Comment: "DSO missing from command line" means that the library **exists**, but it is **not noted** in the **command line**. (Or linkage with the library in the command line prepends the file which uses the library). Since `libstdc++.so` library is included by default, then probably some linker option disables it. You could start debugging with inspecting exact command line (printed with `make VERBOSE=1`)

Comment: Thanks. I've added the output from `make VERBOSE=1` into the question.

Comment: `/usr/bin/gcc` - This is **C** compiler, but file `methane-water-integration.cpp` (like any other file with `.cpp` extension) should be compiler with **C++** compiler. Looks like `gcc` is incorrectly set as C++ compiler in your environment. E.g. like you set `CXX` environment variable or `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` CMake variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I understand what you are saying. So as not to confuse things, I've deleted the build environment and I'm trying again. I've added info concerning C/C++ on my main post.

Comment: Well, the configuration log looks correct. Probably, the project itself suppresses usage of g++ for linking, because it consist from the C++ code without exception throwing (and without other things which would require RTTI). Actually, in the faulted source https://github.com/gromacs/gromacs/blob/main/api/nblib/samples/methane-water-integration.cpp I see no exceptions usage. Not sure why the linker emits such error...

Comment: BTW, the project sets LINKER_LANGUAGE property for one of the linked library: `LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX` ([api/nblib/CMakeLists.txt#L67](https://github.com/gromacs/gromacs/blob/main/api/nblib/CMakeLists.txt#L67)). Note sure why they do that, as CMake usually is able to autodetect such things. Do you build the newest project? (The commit introduced `LINKER_LANGUAGE` is about 2 years old).